# Align an array horizontally to the center of the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, arrays

I am trying to make an array align to the center of the page.

My search for the answer was fruitless as all of the questions (that I have find) refer to the alignment of the array elements and not the array itself.

I have tried using the `center` environment but didn't work. Also the same happened with the command `\centering` that I came across (although I may have used it wrong).

So how can I center the array to the center of the page?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{listings}

\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the `fleqn` option? By the way, `amsmath` should be loaded before `fontspec`.

Comment: @egreg thank you for your suggestion, but that changes the position of everything and not only of the array. I want the equations to remain in the left side of the page. I know about the `amsmath`, you have told me that in the past and I use it always! in this case I just copied and pasted some fragments of my preamble and that's why it is loaded after `fontspec`. :)

Comment: But you've put the `array` inside `equation*` so `fleqn` says you want it flush left...

Comment: @cfr yes but the `fleqn` option is global so there must be a way to change only one element (the array in this instant).

Comment: @cfr also I just used the `equation` enviroment out of habbit, it doesn't need to be that. Check egreg's answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving only the essential parts:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

% these two packages are only for the example
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{centermath}
 {\begin{center}$\displaystyle}
 {$\end{center}}


\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,dt=\log t
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{centermath}
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{array}
\end{centermath}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]